# Java can't add to a list

Tags: java, list

I am new in Java and I have a Student class, and another class in which I try to add an attribute - a list of students. However, when I try to call .add on that list, it gives me an error:

```
    private List<Student> listStuds = new ArrayList<Student>(); 


    public void setStudents(Student... studs)
    {
        for (Student arg : studs) {
           listStuds.add(studs);
        }

    }
```

It says that it can't find any suitable method for add, any idea why ?

```
 Error:(22, 25) java: no suitable method found for add(com.company.Student[])
method java.util.Collection.add(com.company.Student) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; com.company.Student[] cannot be converted to com.company.Student)
method java.util.List.add(com.company.Student) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; com.company.Student[] cannot be converted to com.company.Student)
```

Comment: listStuds.add(arg); -- Explanation: studs is your array. arg the current student of the iteration. You cannot add a whole array with the add method.

Comment: @BeginnersSake: it is an array however, so for-each works.

Comment: It is an array of Sutdent. Look at the exception

Comment: studs is an array of Student, whereas arg is of class Student, you want to change it to listStuds.add(arg)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add the complete array of Student, instead add just a single student every loop.

```
private List<Student> listStuds = new ArrayList<Student>(); 


    public void setStudents(Student... studs)
    {
        for (Student arg : studs) {
           listStuds.add(arg);
        }

    }
```